# Help Understanding Line in .bashrc

Tags: 13.04, bashrc, scripts, pam-environment

I've tried looking everywhere to determine what this line does in my .bashrc. The reason I want to know is because now ~/.pam_environment is *recommended*. This is the line:

```
[[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

I think I've narrowed it to the condition checks to make sure the `nvm.sh` file exists and that it is larger than 0 bytes. But I don't understand what follows. `&&` normally means "and" but I don't understand why that would be necessary after a check and also why the `.` is not attached to the filename.

Basically what I want to know is, how would I put this in my `.pam_environment` file which only takes assigment expressions.

**Edit:** This line currently allows me to run NVM from the terminal but I'd really like to know just for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct that `[[ -s ... ]` checks whether a file exists. If it does, it will exit with the status `0`, and if it doesn't, it will exit as `1` (i.e. fail).

The `&&` command/operator/whatever runs the next command if the command before it succeeded (i.e. the exit status is `0`). `||`, on the contrary, runs the next command if the command before failed (i.e. not `0`).

Having `.` before the filename (with whitespace in-between) runs the file, but also keeps any environmental variable changes it does. For example, if I make `test.sh` as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bar
BAR=baz
BAZ=foo
PATH="FOO:$PATH"
```

and I run `. path/to/test.sh`, there will be new variables: `FOO`, `BAR`, and `BAZ`, and `PATH` will be updated. Notice that `source`, I think, does the same as `.`. **EDIT**: Yes, `source` and `.` are synonyms in bash.

Comment: So would this be possible to put in the .pam_environment file since variable are being set for the session?

Comment: @AdamBeck I doubt it. Apparently the syntax is very limited (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables). I'd recommend going through `nvm.sh` and copying the variable assignments to `.pam_environment`.